# Chrome issue, mousewheel scrolling iframes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, scroll

I've been searching over internet with success, I appreciate if someone can help me.

My problem is, seems that last Google Chrome version has created a bug/or not with scrolling using the mousewheel. I will try explain the issue in the better way.

**Case scenario:**

I have a page **with a IFRAME**, the **IFRAME has a vertical scroll and his parent window too.** In the past **when I start scrolling inside IFRAME and when a reach to the end/top the scrolling continues by the parent window**, however this behavior has change now when a reach to the end/top the scrolling stops...

Anyone has an idea about that?
Is this a bug? 
Is this a configuration?
Can I do something with codding?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New versions of different browsers do not support iframe properly. Moreover it is now focus oriented. It scrolls only the part of page on which the mouse cursor is and if you want to scroll parent page change your cursor focus.

Posts of linkedin also go like this.

Comment: So why before this was working? anyway in Firefox still working? :S it will change in firefox as well?